# Swift UIScrollView not scrolling but responding to setContentOffset and Delegate responds

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift

Getting a really bizarre incident with a `UIScrollView` here which just refuses to scroll. I set it up in my StoryBoard and set the `contentSize` correctly in my `ViewDidLoad`. I double checked to ensure that it was `Scrollable` etc, yet it's just not working. I set `scrollView.setContentOffset()` and it scrolls fine with a lovely animation and the `ScrollViewDidScroll` delegate get's called. So, with that said any reason why it may not be scrolling with drag gestures?

Things I've checked:
- `UserInteraction` Enabled on itself, all `sub/superviews`.
- `Scrollable`.
- Toggled: `DelaysContentTouches` and `CancellableContentTouches`.

I'm out of ideas. Currently using `Xcode 6 Beta 1`. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It isn't scrolling with drag gestures because of auto layout.  In viewDidLoad, auto layout will reset the content size after you define it.  You have two options:  you can disable auto layout, or you can set contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:10, height:10)
}
```

Comment: He's only gone and done it. Thank you so much, solved the issue straight away. That should teach me for not using AutoLayout until swift came along. Over all the years since it's been out, I never opted for AutoLayout as I thought it was a hassle. Been using it for a couple of months now and really like it. Guess I'll have to learn all these little tidbits as I go. Onward and upward!